# UWP Cordova app - Channel URI gets expired after 30 days

Tags: cordova, uwp, cordova-plugins, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

We have implemented one UWP cordova app. Currently we are facing issue with channel uri. To get the notification on windows device, we need to send channel uri and device id. But if user won't open the application, channel uri will get expire after 30 days. If user won't open the app within 30 days, user will not receive any notification further. May I know, is there any work around in which we can update the channel uri at backend when app is inactive? Is there any possibility that we can update channel uri in background or when app is not active?

We tried with `corodva-plugin-background-mode`, but still it's not working. If you guys have any suggestions, do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Must you update the channel uri when the app is inactive? Why not when the app is launched?

Comment: Issue is that, user is not frequently opening the app. Hence channel uri will get expire after 30 days. On app launched, is already implemented. Looking to avoid channel uri expiration.

Comment: You can try to download the [Push and periodic notifications sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/push-and-periodic-de225603) for Windows 8.1 and re-use its source code and/or the pattern it demonstrates to periodically renew its channel in the background.

Comment: Thanks Breeze.. I checked that example. Its more about tiles.. Do windows have silent notification feature like android and ios? If you know anything please do let me know.

Comment: Have you seen the [Raw notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/raw-notification-overview)?